# Return Value of Map.length when run an empty Map

Tags: dictionary, dart

So,I was writing some code and stuck in an unusual problem.I am working on flutter using dart and code somewhat looks like this:

```
class Cart {
  Map<String, String> _item;

  void itemCount()
  {
    var count =_item.length;
    print(count);
  }

}

void main()
{
Cart cart =Cart();
  cart.itemCount();
}
```

I had tried this code in the dartpad and I am getting the error:

**TypeError: C.JSNull_methods.get$length is not a functionError: TypeError: C.JSNull_methods.get$length is not a function**

I am looking for why the length function is not working when the Map is empty but works fine if map is not **NUll**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a map object. you are just declaring map but not initialising, that's why you are facing this error.

Changing declaring line in following manner.

```
Map<String, String> _item = Map();
```